How to solve this TypeError in Next.Js?
Image of the error displayed on client-side screen
Error message:
⨯ src\models\user.model.ts (45:1) @ 
⨯ Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'User')
43 | );
44 |

45 | const User =
| ^
46 |   (mongoose.models.User as mongoose.Model) ||
47 |   mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
48 |
○ Compiling /_error ...
✓ Compiled /_error in 5.8s (252 modules)
GET / 404 in 118ms
○ Compiling /_not-found ...
⚠ Fast Refresh had to perform a full reload due to a runtime error. 

Below is the code in the user.model.ts file.
import mongoose from "mongoose";

export interface TUser extends mongoose.Document {
  username: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  watchlist: string[];
  isVerified: boolean;
  verifyCode: string;
  verifyCodeExpiry: Date;
}

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema<TUser>(
  {
    username: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Username is required"],
      unique: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Email is required"],
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Password is required"],
    },
    watchlist: {
      type: [String],
    },
    isVerified: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    verifyCode: {
      type: String,
    },
    verifyCodeExpiry: {
      type: Date,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

const User =
  (mongoose.models["User"] as mongoose.Model<TUser>) ||
  mongoose.model<TUser>("User", userSchema);

export default User;

My mongoDb cluster is running fine without any pauses and the connection string is also correct.
Please help me with this error.I have been trying to solve it for 2 days.
The application was running fine 2 days ago but suddenly this error popped up.

Never mind I solved it. I messed around for a while and found the solution. const User =   (mongoose.models?.User as mongoose.Model<TUser>) ||   mongoose.model<TUser>("User", userSchema);  I just had to add the '?' because almighty typescript couldn't handle undefined ffs.
